# Can you apply transformation matrices after running your pixel shaders?

Tags: c++, graphics, shader, directx

I'm working with images, and I was tasked to extend the amount of image post-processing effects that we can perform on our images. Certain required effects need pixel data for calculations, so I created a few pixel shaders to do the job, and they work fine.

The problem is that the images need to be transformable, i.e. they need to be able to rotate, zoom in and out, pan, etc. The creation of all these textures, the algorithms to do the post-processing, they're all slowing the program down. I need a way to do these transformations without completely re-doing every effect. Some of the images the program works on are multi-gigabyte images, so I can't really do the obvious thing of caching the images after transformations for later use.

I'm looking for some sort of reasonable solution here. I'm not a graphics guy, but I can't imagine that similar programs with post-processing redo the post processing every time you pan. My best guess is saving off the last texture and applying the transformations on that, but I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: *"I can't imagine that similar programs with post-processing redo the post processing"* - When the scene has changed then the rendering has to be repeated. When a movie is rendered, then each single image in the sequence has to be rendered separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying "images" I assume you mean 2D textures you load and apply some post-pro effects. If that's the case just create a render target and render to that with all the post-effects. 
Then rotate/pan a quad with that texture attached (a simplistic texture-fetching fragment shader will be required). Rerender that texture in case the post-pro parameters change.

If, on the other hand, you have a 3D scene, then there is no going around it, you have to render it each frame.

If my assumptions are wrong, it would be best if you provided more details on your case.